# Generic class accepts primitive type and string

Tags: c#, generics, collections

How do i create a generic type which `accepts only a type of Integer, Long and String.`

I know we can restrict a type for a single class or by implementing an interface with below code

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T:Integer{ }
```

or to handle int,long but not string

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> where T:struct
```

Is it possible to create a generic which accepts only a type of Integer, Long and String?

Comment: Are you sure generics are what you want here?  Generics are generally employed to be used across the board.  What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Moo-Juice this was asked by interviewer. I asked the need, he replied `that is requirement` :(

Comment: My answer would be "You can't, and if you could it wouldn't be properly generic anyway. Write three separate classes instead."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could potentially not have the constraints in the class declaration, but do some type-checking in a static constructor:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    static MyGenericClass() // called once for each type of T
    {
        if(typeof(T) != typeof(string) &&
           typeof(T) != typeof(int) &&
           typeof(T) != typeof(long))
            throw new Exception("Invalid Type Specified");
    } // eo ctor
} // eo class MyGenericClass<T>
```

Edit:

As Matthew Watson points out above, the real answer is "You can't and shouldn't".  If your interviewer believes *that* to be incorrect, then you probably don't want to work there anyway ;)

Comment: Is it possible to make compile time check? This restricts at runtime

Comment: @Billa, no but you can add some additional interfaces  to lessen the possible cases such as `IComparable, IConvertible`

Comment: You _could_ declare factory methods for each valid type, thus the only way to construct the object is compile-time checked. Even so, you could always _declare_ a `MyGenericClass<SomeInvalidType>` just never be able to instantiate/assign/use it.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, "never" is a bit too strong - with full trust permissions you can do all sorts of nasty things, [including creating instances where no constructor was run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx).

Comment: @Lucero haha, fair enough. You can still apply the runtime check as above, but this would provide, let's say, _some_ assurances at compile time that everything is OK short of tomfoolery.

Comment: @Billa but why would you want this restriction? Generic meant to be generic. The restriction is used only when you want perform a specific process inside the class that is not possible to all classes. So what you want to do that requires this restriction?

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi It was an interview question... sooooo who knows why?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use constructors to show what values are acceptable then store the value in an object. Like the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    Object value;

    public MyClass(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyClass(long value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyClass(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```